# How to debug into process with VS when dll files have to be in specific application directories?

Tags: c#, java, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2012

I would like to debug a Java process from a Visual Studio 2012 session.  My projects are C# and C++.  To run the application normally and test my code I have post-build events to copy my output dlls to separate/specific folders for the Java application.

Is it possible to attach a debug process to the java thread without changing the target build directories of my projects?

Answer (score 0):

On Project-> Properties -> Debug tab select "start external program".

You may also need to adjust "working directory" and arguments. Select debugger type you need (if autodetect does not work the way you need).

Comment: The program is started with a large batch file, about 100 lines, even after I took out the junk.  The final command that starts the process is %start_cmd% "%AppDir%\bin\javaw" -classpath "foodirectories" including some other stuff.  I have tried adding my dll locations to the classpath but it still does not find the dlls, they have to be in the %AppDir%\bin\ directory.  I am curious if I could add multiple "bin" directories to the final start command.  Then I could start the batch file and attach the debug process to the javaw.exe process.  I have tried adding to %PATH% as well, doesn't work.

Comment: @JaredBolin - I don't know. I see that my answer is unrelated to the question - did not realize you want to reconfigure Java launcher to pick up libraries from locations they are dropped instead of building what it expects by default.

Comment: I have been able to just set the build directories for each project to the nessasary app directories, probably not ideal but it works. Did a little digging to try and find a method to stick into the batch file, but cannot find a solution.  Thanks